# Engine Control Unit theory regarding highest priority task?

Tags: control-theory

I am changing career paths and will be working on ECUs/VCUs and associated downstream electronic control modules. I am interested to find a research starting point in terms of Real-Time-Operating-Systems as related to Automotive applications and I figured that the highest priority task in Automotive applications might be braking or fire-related. Is this assumption correct and if not, what (in modern automotive design) is considered the highest priority task to deal with?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Which cars have fire sensors?

Comment: You may find going back to some of the early systems : J and K jetronic etc will help as the docs had some tidy block diagrams to outline the function ... not sure if they provide that for the newer stuff now.